# How to change password in SSH

Tags: ssh

So here's the situation: I'm new to my job so I still have no idea what they are talking about like this one, my boss tells me to change my password in docs2comply.com by SSH.

I don't know what the heck he meant by that. But he said that I'll ask some co workers later but I want to make an impression so I need to figure out this myself. A little help here would be really appreciated.

So if anyone here knows what I mean please guide me through this.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Just ask your peers or boss. You're not making any kind of good impression by asking Internet strangers how to do your job. There's no shame in admitting you don't know, unless you've previously lied about your level of competence in order to get the job.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you're on unix/linux, then login to your ssh server like this:

```
ssh -l <username> <servername>
```

this'll prompt you for password, if you have not yet transferred your ssh keys to the server.
If you're on Windows, then use putty for doing the same.

Then after logging in, do this:

```
passwd
```

this will prompt your for your current password on the server and then new password

Comment: shall i type it in the command prompt? it says there that ssh is not recognized as an internal command and should i include the <><>? im using windows

Comment: No, you're not suppose to include <><>. I think you're on Windows, so install putty

Comment: ill comment after i tried it ok? please dont go away sir. hehe

Comment: sir there are lots of download links here http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html which one should i pick?

Comment: probably the first one http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe, can't tell you as I've never used putty

Comment: thanks man. i figured it out. thanks a lot. I would kiss you if you wer beside me. lol