# Allow an SFTP user to change password on Windows Server

Tags: remote-desktop, passwords, user-accounts, windows-server-2016

We have a Windows Server instance hosting some web applications and an SFTP server. There's a single user with access to the SFTP server. How do I allow them to change their password remotely?

Note: The user doesn't have RDP access. And in OpenSSH, I've restricted them to SFTP only (`ForceCommand internal-sftp`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change password in SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/571273/how-to-change-password-in-ssh)

Comment: @harrymc It doesn't. Even though SFTP uses SSH as an underlying protocol, the question you mentioned assumes that there is a shell available. In this case, there isn't, as the SSH channel is connected directly to the SFTP service. Not to mention the fact that the way to change a password in the question you mentioned is for Unix-like systems, not for Windows.

Comment: Without a shell, I'm not sure that there's an answer.